# jquery masked input throws "Object doesn't support property or method 'mask'"

Tags: javascript, jquery, maskedinput

I am using "jquery.maskedinput" with jquery v 2.2.1.  When the page loads I get an "Object doesn't support property or method 'mask'" exception.

**Here is the view:**

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit Profile";
 }

<h2>Edit Profile</h2>
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Edit", "Profile", new AjaxOptions { @HttpMethod = "Post", OnComplete = "processMessageFromController" }, new { id = "changePasswordForm" }))
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Email)
    <div style="background-color: #ecf0f1; width: 45%; border-radius: 15px;">
        <fieldset>
            <div id="phone" class="form-group" style="margin-top: 15px;">
                <label class="col-lg-4 control-label" style="margin-top: 9px;">Telephone:</label>
                <div>
                    <input type="text" id="telephone" value="5551234567" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
}
@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.maskedinput.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/Custom/profileFuctions.js"></script>
```

**Here is the javascript:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#telephone").mask("(999) 999-9999");
});
```

**From the _Layout:**

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

**From BundleConfig:**

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"));
```

I see a bunch of Q's and A's here but none of them are helping.  Can someone shed some light on this for me?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: I the maskedinput JS file loading? What does WebInspector, Firebug, etc... network panel show for that file? Can you navigate to `http://host/~/Scripts/jquery.maskedinput.min.js`?

Comment: Yes it is loading up and I can navigate to it.  All required .js files are loaded and present in the Sources tab of the Dev Tools

Comment: It's is likely a JS loading issue. I would remove all JS but jQuey and the mask plugin and/or copy the HTML that's generated and create a JSFiddle to whittle down the source.

Comment: This is weird , all your code seems fine. Just try your code with nothing but a input field and only the mask plugin in the page and check what happens.